# Calculating Expectation Value of a dependent random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Given the density function $f_{XY}(x,y) = 6x$y, when $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $0 \leq y \leq \sqrt{x}$,

how do I calculate $\mathbb{E}(Y)$?

I've tried using the law of Total Expectation, but I'm not sure I got a logical result.

Comment: You can marginalize out $Y$. Integrate the $f(x, y)$ with respect to x and put a limit of integration as domain of $X$.

Comment: I integrated fx(x) with respect to x.  I got 3/4.  And then E(3/4) is 3/4. This doesn't use y.

Did I misunderstand? Should I have integrated fxy(x,y)?

Comment: Yes, you have to intgegrate $f_{XY}(x,y)$ with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The marginal density of $Y$ is given by $F_Y(y)=\int f_{XY} (x,y) dx=\int_{y^{2}}^{1} 6xy dx$ since $y \leq \sqrt x$ translates to $x \geq y^{2}$. Hence $f_Y(y)= 3y(1-y^{4})$ for $ 0 \leq y \leq 1$. Now $EY=\int_0^{1} yf_Y (y) dy$. I will let you carry out the integration.

You can also find $EY$ directly from the formula $EY=\iint yf(x,y)dy$ where the integral is a double integral over the given region.